# two kafka consumer in same group and one partition

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, kafka-consumer-api

I have kafka topic and one partiton  .When i create consumer missed to mention the group .id . there are 2 different consumer for the same partition . 
I can receive messages and my flink source extends FlinkKafkaConsumer011.

Ideally one consumer should receive message since its a same group but in my case both the consumers are receiving messages not sure why ???.

To test have restarted one of my job and newly started consumer is not picking where it has left because other consumer is commiting offset it seems.

Flink 1.6.0 
Kafka 0.11.2

Comment: Check how consumer group.id is generated by `FlinkKafkaConsumer011`. It might be some random id. `group.id` is mandatory property, so if you not pass it, framework has to do that. Otherwise `KafkaConsumer` would threw exception

Comment: forgot to mention if  group.id is null then group.id is "" Hence it didnt threw exception
When i debugged found both the consumer groupid is same .still wondering both consumer got message defeating one partition and one consumer kafka principle it overrides offset